# force close error simple form not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="MARKETING SUPERVISOR"/>


                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                 <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="CHALLAN"
                        android:gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >


                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Perm.IncmTax Num."
                        android:gravity="center"/>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:gravity="center" >
                        <requestFocus />
                    </EditText>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Customer Code Number"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
                    android:gravity="center"/>
                <EditText
                     android:id="@+id/editText2"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:inputType="number" 
                     android:gravity="center">

                    <requestFocus />
              </EditText>
            </LinearLayout>

              <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Customer Name"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText3"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />
            </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
             <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Customer Address"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
              <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText4"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />
        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Name of Cosignee"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText5"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Address of Cosignee"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
              <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText6"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />
        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Sales Order"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
             <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/editText7"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:inputType="number" >
                  <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Customer Order Date"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
             <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="date" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

             <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="INVOICE DETAILS"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Invoice Number"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number" >
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Date of issue of Invoice"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="date" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Time of Issue of Invoice"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Date of Dispatch of Goods"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
              <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="date" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Time of Dispatch of Goods"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Description of Goods"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />
        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Quantity Total"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
             <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/editText7"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:inputType="number" >
                  <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

               <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Unit"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
             <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="date" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Total Amount"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
             <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="date" />
                </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I am getting the "Force Close" on the execution of xml code.
The error log is giving errors like:
1)TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
2)Unable to update index for central
and some many more weird ones

Comment: Post your LogCat and **relative code**

Comment: A little off topic, but i would highly suggest you also try and clean up your layout. Your using a lot of linearlayouts which is going to be very costly as far as rendering goes. As simpler layout is easier on the system, and easier to debug. I would suggest you look into RelativeLayout as it is very powerful for creating more complex layouts:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to give different id's to your `texViews` try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >    

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="MARKETING SUPERVISOR"/>            

    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

         <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="CHALLAN"
                android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Perm.IncmTax Num."
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:gravity="center" >
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Customer Code Number"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <EditText
             android:id="@+id/editText2"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:inputType="number" 
             android:gravity="center">

            <requestFocus />
      </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Customer Name"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Customer Address"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
      <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />
 </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Name of Cosignee"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Address of Cosignee"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
      <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Sales Order"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText7"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:inputType="number" >
          <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Customer Order Date"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="date" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="INVOICE DETAILS"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Invoice Number"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText13"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Date of issue of Invoice"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText15"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="date" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Time of Issue of Invoice"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText17"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Date of Dispatch of Goods"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText19"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="date" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Time of Dispatch of Goods"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText21"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />
</LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView22"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Description of Goods"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText23"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView24"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Quantity Total"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText25"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:inputType="number" >
          <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView26"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Unit"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText27"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="date" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView28"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Total Amount"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText29"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="date" />
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think you missed renaming a couple of the ids. But +1 anyways for the solution.

Comment: Thanks. But I did not think I missed any id, because eclipse would have give me an error, and I tested on my phone and it works fine.  Can you tell me which one I miss?

Comment: i see textView1 added a couple times.

Comment: Thanks, it should be fixed now. I think I copied the wrong code :)